# Permanently changing the UserAgent string in Firefox 4

Tags: php, firefox, user-agent

Here is the deal.  I have created some HTML/Javacript dashboards that will be displayed on big screen displays.  The displays are powered by thin clients running WinXP and Firefox 4.  There will also be a desktop version as well.  I would like to use one url (dashboard.php) and then redirect to the appropriate page.  I need to be able to differentiate between the big screen displays and someone using Firefox from the desktop.  My thought was to permanently change the UserAgent string on the big screen deployments and use browser sniffing to determine which version to forward the user too.  The problem is, it appears that FF4 has removed the ability to change the UA string permanently.  Anyone have any ideas on how I could do this or an idea on how I can otherwise differentiate between big screens and a desktop user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the IP address of the computers displaying on the big screens? Especially if the big displays are on an internal network, assign them a static IP address and use that to identify the computers. Other than that, just pass a get string saying `?view=bigDisplay` or similar. You can simply put in your code

```
$bigDisplay = (isset($_GET['view'])&&$_GET['view']=='bigDisplay');
```

then you would have a boolean of whether to display the `bigDisplay` code.

Edit:
also, just googled and found this: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/806795

Comment: I was trying to avoid using a query string parameter so that I would have a simple URL.  I also saw that article as well so I will give that a try.  IP address is a possibility although I have to check with  network admin about getting static IPs for these devices.  They normally use DHCP.

Comment: I tried the general.useragent.override setting in about:config and that seemed to do it.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: We use big displays in our lobby. The browser is set to full screen so the URL isn't seen by anyone. Also the way I suggested to use the query string, it would only need to be on the display computers. Any other computers wouldn't need the query string to work.

Comment: The concern is not with people seeing the URL. The issue is with how these dashboards are being developed and deployed. The bigboards go out first and people are accessing them with there browsers even though the experience has not been optimized yet.  We do not want to use a second URL when the optimized version is ready.  Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If IP address detection is not an option, you could simply set a cookie for the big screen machines.

You can do this by creating a special URL, e.g., `/bigscreen` which will set the cookie with an expiration date far into the future. Then in your script, simply check for the existence of that cookie.

Using a cookie means that you don't have to worry about continuing to append query strings to subsequent URLs.

**Edit:** You could even manually place the cookie in Firefox if you wish to avoid visiting a special URL. There are add-ons to facilitate that.

Comment: Again, that still requires seperate URLs for the desktop and big screen version.  Which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @Donavan: My point is that it's just as much effort to go in and change the user agent string in the browser as it is to visit a particular URL just one time. You could even manually place the cookie within Firefox if you wish.

Comment: Manually setting up the cookie could be an option.  I will have to look at that.  I need to test on browser and machine restarts to make sure that the cookie persists.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```
if((screen.width >= 1024) && (screen.height >=768))
{
    window.location= '?big=1';
}
```

PHP

```
if($_GET['big'] == 1){
    setcookie('big', 1, 0);
}
```

Then just read cookie, and that's it...

Comment: Testing for screen size is not reliable enough to discern between the two scenarios.  Setting the cookie still requires a query string parameter or a different URL to know when to set it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the UA string just fine in Firefox 4.  The `general.useragent.override` preference will let you set it to whatever you want.

What was removed was a way to modify parts of the UA string without overriding the whole thing.